# Realm: Swift `let` property cannot be marked as dynamic

Tags: swift, realm

I am using Xcode 7.2, Swift 2.1.1. I have a Realm model object below

```
class B: Object {
    dynamic let lists = List<A>() 
}
```

But the Swift compiler gives me an error saying:

> Property cannot be marked as dynamic because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C

I saw Realm's documentation that says:

> Realm model properties need the dynamic var attribute in order for these properties to become accessors for the underlying database data.
>
> There are two exceptions to this: List and RealmOptional properties
>   cannot be declared as dynamic because generic properties cannot be
>   represented in the Objective-C runtime, which is used for dynamic
>   dispatch of dynamic properties, and should always be declared with `let`

But declaring `let` doesn't seem to solve this case now. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you quoted includes the following (emphasis mine):

> List and RealmOptional properties **cannot be declared as dynamic** because generic properties cannot be represented in the Objective-C runtime, […], and should always be declared with `let`.

This means your property should be declared like so:

```
let lists = List<A>()
```

The Realm Swift documentation recently gained a [property declaration cheatsheet](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#property-cheatsheet) which hopefully clarifies the requirements for the different types of declarations.